# Arm always in collision when running get_state_validity

Tags: ros, collision, pr2-arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While running the [Checking State Validity tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning%20Scene/Checking%20State%20Validity) the robot arm is always red (except when joint limits are violated), even when there should be no collisions. After some debugging effort, I found that **head_pan_link+double_stereo_link** were always in collision. Otherwise, the tutorial seems to work in that the arm turns blue when joint limits are violated and collision markers appear where they should.

ROS Version: Electric

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12514/arm-always-in-collision-when-running-get_state_validity/) by [robbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1365/robbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2012-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the report - it looks like the positions of some of the links subtly changed in the latest release of pr2_description and that we need a slightly altered set of collision operations in pr2_arm_navigation.  I'll do a release this week, but in the meantime if you add the following line to get_state_validity.cpp at line 33 things should work (this line just disables all collisions except those that matter for the arm):

collision_models.disableCollisionsForNonUpdatedLinks("right_arm");

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1365/robbie/) on 2012-01-03**:
Thank you, adding the line worked.